# How to run this angular $interval function just three times (3 loops)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I would like to run the following function from my controller, using interval and producing three different avatars in the view template.

At the moment, it produces just one avatar.png , but I would love to produce three different.

So how can I set the html also so it displays three different images?
Here is my code:

controller:

```
$scope.capture = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
}

$interval (function(){
    $scope.capture();
}, 1500);
```

And my template for the canvas where image is drawn:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

So basically, I want after 1.5 seconds an image is drawn and total images drawn should be 3. Each image with it's own canvas id different.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `$timeout`

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    $timeout (function(){
        $scope.capture();
    }, 1500*i);
}
```

This will execute your function 3 times. You may need to write logic to draw image in different canvas with different IDs.

Comment: That will work fine. Any ideas as to the logic to draw the image three times to the canvas with different ids?

Comment: There are different ways actually. If it's fixed that you want 3 only you can have 3 canvas tag in your html with IDs canvas0, canvas1 and canvas2 and pass i as argument like `$scope.capture(i)`. Note - you need to wrap your timeout inside self calling function.

Comment: In your answer there is a small problem. For example, if the second call is `$timeout` will be performed for a long time, for example 2 seconds, the third call would be called before the second call.